# Is it possible to create an xml from json in the browser, then download that xml?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, browser, download

I'm about to create a client side app, which at the end should create and xml file and offer to the user to download it to the computer.
Is it possible to create and download xml from the browser?

Comment: yes, it is possible to do both

Comment: Process of creating an xml string is really no different than creating an html string from an array or object. Break this into two parts and research both separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```js
function downloadXMLFromJSON(jsonString) {
  let fileName = 'sample.xml';
  let xmlStr = new X2JS().json2xml_str(JSON.parse(jsonString));
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = fileName;
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new File([xmlStr], fileName, {type: 'text/xml'}));
  a.click();
}
downloadXMLFromJSON(`{"x": "a", "y": "b"}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/abdmob/x2js/master/xml2json.min.js"></script>
```

You're going to need an external library for converting JSON to XML (x2js in this case). Then you can use an in memory `a` tag with `download` attribute to download xml file.

Comment: unfortunately, your code doesn't work in (at least) firefox - chrome is really loose in allowing sites to initiate a download like that without any user interaction!! IE doesn't like the `\`\`` - Edge also issues an error about "Function expected" - so the fact that this works on the worlds most insecure browser is not really an answer :p